# How could I add nodes of a treeview as folders from a remote directory with WinSCP and C#

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, directory-structure, winscp

I'm trying to create a tree view to search for a directories in a remote server using FTP/SFTP connections, What I'm trying to do is start filling the tree view with all the available directories starting with the home directory such as the following example:

```
Home---->SubFolder
    |
    |---->Another Folder
    |
    |---->MyOtherFolder
```

Then when the user start clicking in each folder it start to display their subdirectories from the tree view as the follwoing example (clicking in Another Folder):

```
Home ---->SubFolder
     |
     |---->Another Folder -------> MyFolder1
     |                  | -------> MyFolder2
     |
     |---->MyOtherFolder
```

I'm trying to get those folders but it's throwing an exception, also it is gathering files, not folders....

this is the code that I have....

```
private void FillTree()
{
   SessionOptions SessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
   Session MySession = new Session();

   SessionOptions.HostName = InterfaceValues[0];
   SessionOptions.UserName = InterfaceValues[2];
   SessionOptions.Password = InterfaceValues[3];
   SessionOptions.PortNumber = Convert.ToInt32(InterfaceValues[1]);

   if (string.Compare(InterfaceValues[9], "FTP", true) == 0)
       SessionOptions.Protocol = WinSCP.Protocol.Ftp;
   else if (string.Compare(InterfaceValues[9], "SFTP", true) == 0)
   {
        SessionOptions.Protocol = WinSCP.Protocol.Sftp;
        SessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath = InterfaceValues[12];
        SessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = InterfaceValues[10];
   }

   try
   {
       MySession.Open(SessionOptions);

       foreach (RemoteFileInfo info in MySession.EnumerateRemoteFiles("/", "*",  EnumerationOptions.AllDirectories))
       {
          if (info.IsDirectory)
             tvRemoteDirectory.Nodes.Add(info.Name);
       }

   MySession.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MySession.Close();
     MessageBox.Show("Not possible to connect to " + InterfaceValues[0] + "\nError Message: " + ex.Message);
      this.Close();
}
```

The exception that I'm getting is:

`{WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Error listing directory '/jpm_icl'. ---> WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Permission denied.
Error code: 3
Error message from server: Permission Denied!`

Any idea what could I do at this point?

Comment: Either get permission or ignore the error.

Comment: I tried with this:

`RemoteDirectoryInfo RemoteDirectory = MySession.ListDirectory("/");

 foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileinfo in RemoteDirectory.Files)
 {
     
     //tvRemoteDirectory.Nodes.Add(fileinfo.Name);
 }
`

but it's retrieving "." and ".." and "jpm_icl" but I have no Idea what about "jpm_icl", I can't see that folder

Comment: When do you get the exception? In the `EnumerateRemoteFiles` loop? Where you can't see the `jpm_icl` folder?

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl, Yes, In the loop, at the 3rd time it throw the exception... What I mean, `jmp_icl` does not exist in the remote server, I'm not sure if is a hidden folder.

Comment: I already checked the folder and the option "show hidden files and folders" in windows server and is on, not sure what is `jmp_icl`

Comment: Connect with WinSCP GUI and post a screenshot of the root folder + Append a session log file from your code (`Session.SessionLogPath`).

Comment: I solved this. That folder looks like is from someone else, that I don't have access to it. I will post my answer in this post

Answer (score 1):

What I did was this:

ListDirectory function to retrieve all the directories, as I don't want the directory "." and "." I have to exclude it.

```
RemoteDirectoryInfo RemoteDirectory;

     if (RemoteDirectoryPath != "Home")
          RemoteDirectory  = MySession.ListDirectory(RemoteDirectoryPath);
     else
          RemoteDirectory = MySession.ListDirectory("/");
     if (tvRemoteDirectory.SelectedNode.Nodes.Count > 0) tvRemoteDirectory.SelectedNode.Nodes.Clear();

     foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileinfo in RemoteDirectory.Files)
     {                    
        if (fileinfo.IsDirectory)
        {
           if (fileinfo.Name != "." &&
               fileinfo.Name != "..")
               {                                                    
                   TreeNode ChildNode = new TreeNode();
                   ChildNode.Text = fileinfo.Name;
                   ChildNode.ImageIndex = 0;                                                     
                   tvRemoteDirectory.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(ChildNode);
                   tvRemoteDirectory.ExpandAll();
               }          
         }                    
     }
```